# what is the difference between doctrine 2 ,Tablegateway and zend_db?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-db, tablegateway

After exploring a lot about zf2 database and model chapter:
i did not understand what is most preferable for database part whether to use Tablegateway(As mentioned in the document file) or zend_db or doctrine2(ORM).

Like which one more features over others.

i need some clarification here..

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend_DB (zf1 ?) or Zend\DB (zf2) is a components of ZF which contain in it TableGateway.

Doctrine is an ORM (Object Relational Mapper).

Now this post is possibly duplicate of [This question On Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874558/is-it-worth-using-doctrine-2-with-zend-framework)

It says :

> Out-of-the-box Zend_Db is more just an enhanced Database Abstraction Layer on top of PDO, where as Doctrine 2 is a Object Relational Mapper (which sits on top of it's own DBAL).
>
> Doctrine 2 is much better for more complicated domain layers, because
>   all your business logic, persistence logic, etc are separated over
>   multiple classes, so they don't serve multiple roles. Also, because
>   you have more classes - that are cleaner and loosely-coupled - it
>   makes testing them much easier.

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept my answer as best answer if it was what you expected.